# Why do they use references instead of jQuery objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In [this](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/how-to-build-a-star-ratings-jquery-plugin) tutorial, they use containerElement.rating and starElement.rating for storing rating.

The question is : Why?? is it possible to use jQuery objects container and star like

container.rating and star.rating??

In their example, How does it work:

```
star.click(function() {

        containerElement.rating = this.rating;//What does 'this' refer to?? Star or starElement??

        elements.triggerHandler("ratingchanged", {rating: this.rating});
      });
```

Comment: See the jQuery documentation. It guarantees `this` will be the *DOM element* that the click event occurred upon (this is actually how event callbacks -- even "normal ones" -- work in JavaScript in general).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doable/allowable, but not recommended. Nothing says that jquery couldn't suddenly decide to add a `.star` attribute at some point in the future.

If you need to attach your own data to a dom element, then use `someelement.data(key, val)` instead, which adds your data in a method guaranteed to not conflict with any future changes to the DOM specs.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to store objects like you're saying, but I believe this tutorial creates some circular references (JS->DOM->JS) which is bad. They should be using jQuery's [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data) function to avoid circular references, which cause memory leaks.

Comment: Note: this causes memory leaks only in Internet Explorer 7 and earlier. It is not a problem for other browsers, nor IE8+.